# GraphQL error: Variable 'id' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'ID!'

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, react-apollo, aws-appsync

I am using the AWS AppSync service as my GraphQL server. I am passing a mutation GraphQL tag to create a user but somehow I am getting this error in the console:

```
GraphQL error: Variable 'id' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'ID!'
```

The mutation GraphQL tag is like this:

```js
     import gql from 'graphql-tag';

    export default gql`
    mutation addUser ($id:ID!,$name:String!,$email:String!,$number:String!,$gender:String!,$password:String!,$createdAt:String!,$type:String!){
      addUser(
            id:$id,
            name:$name,
            email:$email,
            number:$number,
            gender:$gender,
            password:$password,
            createdAt:$createdAt,
            type:$type
          ){
            id
            name
            email
          }
       }`;
```

and I am passing this GraphQL tag inside my `SignupForm.js` to create a user like this:

```js
    export default graphql(AddUser,{
    props:props=>({
    AddUser:user=>props.mutate({
      variable:user,
      })
    })
    })(SignUpForm);
```

When I call `this.props.AddUser(user)`

where user is signup user details object

I got error mentioned above.

Comment: Can you print your `user`?

Comment: could it be you have a typo and it needs to be `variables: user` instead of `variable: user`?

Comment: thank you very much it is working now

Comment: @TalZ please add your response as an answer so others can quickly find it. 

@Rizwan have you considered the new `Mutation` component? https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/introducing-react-apollo-2-1-c837cc23d926

Answer (score 4):

It seems the problem is a typo in the mutation options:

`{ variable: user }` should be `{ variables: user }` (with an 's')